# How to postpone hiding view when user clicks button again?

Tags: ios, swift

If user clicks button I hide view after 3 seconds using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. However if user again clicks that button I wan't to postpone hiding activity for next more 3 seconds so previous call of hiding will be ignored.

I have tried following code but it hides view after first 3 seconds.

```
    class MyView: UIView {
        private var hideControls: DispatchWorkItem?
        
        func displayControls() {
            isHidden = false
            hideControls?.cancel()
            
            hideControls = DispatchWorkItem {
                print("displayControls: DispatchWorkItem called ")
                self.isHidden = true
            }
            
            if let hideControls = hideControls {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: hideControls)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would try adding an action or target to the button. When it is clicked, cancel current job and create a new one, resetting the timer

Comment: I misunderstanding, you  want to postpone hiding activity for next more 3 seconds so previous call of hiding will be ignored.?

Comment: Hi @luffy_064, button click calls displayControls() which hides view after 3 seconds. However, if user clicks same button again after 2 seconds then I want to hide that view after next 3 seconds instead of first 3 seconds expiry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the previous work you can work with Timer, add the property timer,

```
var timer : Timer?
```

and on your method for hidden use this.

```
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false, block: {[weak self] (_) in
            #add the action that you want
            self?.isHidden = true
        })
```

Br.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a dispatch work item or GCD, use a Timer:

- The Timer is an instance property and is an Optional. It is initially `nil`.
- The Timer is a one-time timer for 3 seconds, and its action method hides the button.
- When the user presses the button, safely invalidate the Timer with `self.timer?.invalidate()` and replace it with a new scheduled Timer — `self.timer=...`

If you think about it, you will see that this solves the problem. No matter whether a timer was already running, pressing the button now means "regardless of what I may have said in the past, three seconds from now is when the button should be hidden."

I use this technique all the time. For instance, I have a game where the user is to be penalized for each ten seconds that goes by without making a move. So if the user moves, I replace the timer with a new ten-second timer. If the user *doesn't* within the (new?) ten-second period, the timer fires and the penalty is applied. (It happens that I then make a new timer, but that wouldn't be the case in your example.)